# I don't find pagefile.sys on any disk

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm looking for file pagefile.sys in a Windows Server 2008, and I don't find it in C: drive or D: drive.

On my Folder Options, it's unchecked "Hide protected o/s files".

Does it mean that server is not using that page memory ? And if it needed then that file will be created?

Answer (score 10):

Run `wmic pagefile list /format` from a command prompt. It will show you all of the pagefile information available for each pagefile on the system including their physical path.

This is the sample output from my workstation:

```
AllocatedBaseSize=16308
CurrentUsage=0
Description=C:\pagefile.sys
InstallDate=20120910154535.664824-240
Name=C:\pagefile.sys
PeakUsage=0
Status=
TempPageFile=FALSE
```